# SQL query to find set of doc_ids where there is maximum intersection of ent_ids

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with O(1M) rows with columns **doc_id** and **ent_id** where (doc_id, ent_id) is the primary key.

```
+--------+--------+
| doc_id | ent_id |
+--------+--------+
|      1 | a      |
|      1 | b      |
|      1 | x      |
|      1 | y      |
|      2 | a      |
|      3 | a      |
|      3 | x      |
|      3 | y      |
|      4 | x      |
|      4 | y      |
+--------+--------+
```

My question is, How do I efficiently find a set of **doc_id**s  ( say I need top 1000 or 5000 doc_ids) where there is maximum intersection of **ent_id**s among that selected set of **doc_id**s?

For example : In the above table,

- say I need top 2 doc_ids where there is maximum intersection among their ent_ids.The result would be - doc_ids = {1,3} with [ common ent_ids={a,x,y}, common ent_ids count=3 ]
- say I need top 3 doc_ids where there is maximum intersection among their ent_ids. The result would be - doc_ids = {1,3,4} with [ common ent_ids={x,y}, common ent_ids count=2 ]

*footnote - If it's not possible do it efficiently with SQL, any direction towards alternative method of doing it in application code would also be helpful. say, convert to csv -> some data-structure[inverted index?]/library + python code -> result set.*

Comment: What is the "selected set of doc_ids"?  What do the numbers mean?  Are those docids (which are not in the sample data) or the size of the sets?

Comment: 'that selected set' -> the set of doc_ids that would comprise the result set.

Comment: the numbers are the number of doc_ids that I want in the result set i.e. size of result set.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: @Strawberry added an examples of expected result

Comment: At 2 or 3, any query is going to be as efficient as any other. At 1000 or 5000, I think you're going to break your computer. It might be best to solve this in application code - employing techniques similar to whatever geneticists do when looking for markers.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, I know, need ton of joins to get this right. Hence asking for an efficient way to do it.

Comment: I don't think that there is a query that satisfies the brief - at least not in versions of MySQL pre 8.0, but let's see what others have to say.

Comment: Possible `group_concat(distinct ent_id order by ent_id)` to get a list of all unique ent_id(s) in ascending order for a `doc_id`. Now some string operations maybe.. just throwing out wild ideas..but as Strawberry suggested, it is better to do it in application code.